# Get all displayed objects from twitter typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-typeahead

I'm using twitter typeahead to show suggestions, it's working fine. But I need to get all the displayed suggestion (objects) as user continues to type. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
        var mCountry = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 10,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'list.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(country) {

                    return {
                        name: country.n,
                        id: country.i
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });

    mCountry.initialize();

    $("#sugg_input").typeahead(null, {
        name: 'countries',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: mCountry.ttAdapter()
    });
```

Comment: Suggestion are only display, when user type first char ?

Comment: no, for all the characters

Comment: You need to display (name + id) in the typehead ?